# Fixed div within a div using position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Could somebody assist me in getting the List items under the listing div to be fixed but scrollable?

```
<div id="listings">
```

So that the listing div is the only box being scrolled when the user wishes to scroll down the page. Essentially leaving everything else fixed. I've mocked it up here http://jsfiddle.net/aQpwt/1/

I've been trying to use position:fixed but it hasn't worked as planned. Could someone help?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Remove the extra divs and please explain what it is you are trying to achieve. My understanding - which is probably inaccurate - is that you want the main scrollbar to control the `<div id="listings">`?

Comment: Why don't you just fix the ads and the sidebar and then set the content's padding-top to the ads height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the CSS class to:

```
#listings {
    float:right;
    width:790px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

and remove the leading `<br>`:

```
<br class="clear" />
```

Comment: @Denver this is he best answer + you shouldn't mix style-based html with css.